# Getting a value from a table inside a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

so I have to write a trigger for a movie rental store database that will log all rentals into a log table saying who rented what movie and when. FYI, this is in sql developer and Im using oracle sql.

Here is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger rentalLogging
after insert on rentals
for each row 
declare 
  customerName varchar2(50);
begin
  select c.name into customerName from customer c 
  join rentals r on c.CUST_ID = r.CUST_ID
  where c.CUST_ID = :NEW.cust_id;

  insert into log_movieRentals values 
  ('customer: ' || customerName || 'rented movie on: ' || current_date);
end;
```

I am getting an error when I try to insert into my rentals table saying the table is mutating and the trigger may not see it.

The reason I need to get the customer name and assign it to a variable is because my rentals table does not contain the customer name but only the customer id and I want to log the customer name in this case.

I thought of creating and using a function that takes a customer id and returns their name in this trigger but I am wondering if there's a way of getting the customer name in this trigger.

Comment: Why do you think you need to join to `rentals` in that query? Look at it again - what would be the effect of commenting out the line starting with `join` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to include the `rentals` table in the query inside your trigger. All the data you need is already in the `new` pseudorecord, and in fact you don't use that table for anything *except* the join - and that would likely to cause the query to find multiple rows, if it was allowed at all.

You can just remove the join:

```
  select c.name into customerName from customer c 
  where c.CUST_ID = :NEW.cust_id;
```

Incidentally, you don't really need the local variable; you could do this in one step with:

```
  insert into log_movieRentals
  select 'customer: ' || c.name || 'rented movie on: ' || current_date
  from customer c
  where c.cust_id = :new.cust_id;
```

It is preferable to specify the target table's column name(s) as part of the table nsert statement too.

Comment: Oh its true I think I overthought this.

Comment: So if I understand this you cannot use the table ur inserting into in a select clause inside the trigger ??

Comment: You can't use the table the trigger is against, no. There are lots of questions about the mutating table error that f you want to do more reading. In this case, you just don't need to anyway.